# Why we treat $d^2f$ as an application of two variables?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $E$ and $F$ two normed spaces and $f$ a function from $E$ to $F$.
We know that \begin{align*} df :&E \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}(E,F) \\ &x \longmapsto df(x) \\ \\ 
d^2f : & E \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}(E, \mathcal{L}(E,F)) \\ & x \longmapsto d^2f(x)  \end{align*}
and $(d^2f(x))(y) \in F,$ for all $x,y \in E.$

Now we define $B$ by :   \begin{align*} B :  \mathcal{L}(E,& \mathcal{L}(E,F)) \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}(E \times E,F) \\ & L \longmapsto B(L)=B_L \\ \end{align*}
Such that, for all $x,y \in E$, $B_L(x,y)=L(x)(y).$

B is an isomorphism  s.t : $\|B_L\|=\|L\|$, for all $L \in\mathcal{L}(E, \mathcal{L}(E,F)).$

---

I understand that when we write that $d^2f(a)(h,k) $ it's in fact $B (d^2f(a)) (h)(k) $ !!
I get confused here a little, can someone explain please?! I think i didn't understand that well !

Comment: In fact, the second derivative is a map $E \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}(E, \mathcal{L}(E,F))$, but life is easier if we identify $\mathcal{L}(E, \mathcal{L}(E,F))$ with $\mathcal{L}(E \times E,F)$.